# The effect of transposing a numpy array on its strides and data buffer

Tags: arrays, numpy, buffer, transpose, stride

Suppose you are given a numpy array

```
x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]], dtype=np.int8)
```

and let's take its transpose.

```
y = x.T
```

My understanding from the numpy documetnation has been that tranpose only modifies the strides of the array, and not its underlying data buffer.

We can verify that by running

```
>> x.data.strides
(2, 1)

>> y.data.strides
(1, 2)
```

However, the data seems to be modified as well

```
>> x.data.tobytes()
b'\x01\x02\x03\x04'

>> y.data.tobytes()
b'\x01\x03\x02\x04'
```

when the expected behavior according to my understanding should be that `y`'s data buffer remains the same as that of `x`, and only the strides change.

Why do we see a different data buffer for `y`? Is perhaps the `data` attribute not showing the underlying memory layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better way to check the data buffer is with the `__array_interface__` pointer:

```
In [8]: y=x.T
In [9]: x.__array_interface__
Out[9]: 
{'strides': None,
 'data': (144597512, False),
 'shape': (2, 2),
 'version': 3,
 'typestr': '|i1',
 'descr': [('', '|i1')]}
In [10]: y.__array_interface__
Out[10]: 
{'strides': (1, 2),
 'data': (144597512, False),
 'shape': (2, 2),
 'version': 3,
 'typestr': '|i1',
 'descr': [('', '|i1')]}
```

Docs to `.data` are:

> In [12]: x.data?
>   memoryview(object)
>   Create a new memoryview object which references the given object.

```
In [13]: x.data
Out[13]: <memory at 0xb2f7cb6c>
In [14]: y.data
Out[14]: <memory at 0xb2f7cbe4>
```

So `y.data` isn't showing the bytes of its buffer, but bytes as traversed by strides.  I'm not sure if there's a way of seeing the `y` databuffer.

```
In [25]: y.base
Out[25]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]], dtype=int8)
```

`x` is CContiguous, `y` is Fcontinguous.

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to @hpaulj good answer :

```
In [7]: frombuffer(x,uint8)
Out[7]: array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=uint8)

In [8]: frombuffer(y,uint8) 
ValueError: ndarray is not C-contiguous

In [9]: frombuffer(np.ascontiguousarray(y),uint8)
Out[9]: array([1, 3, 2, 4], dtype=uint8)
```

shows that `y` is really a view.